# How to temporarily restore an old version of source code?

Tags: mercurial

I need to be able to restore an old version of source code, do some work on it (to generate a lost .exe file), then put back the source code as it is now.

How do I do this using Mercurial?.

The Mercurial project includes both the old and current versions.

NOTE To the people who have marked me down, please tell me why. Before posting this I looked for other questions on this topic. The others seemed to address *permanent* restores, mine is about *temporary* ones. If you marked me down because I do not know the answer - this is why I am asking the question!

Comment: Great answer to the people voting down without commenting why.

Comment: There is no permanent or temporary updates. The working folder is a snapshot to a certain point in time, and you can go back and forth in the history of the repo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is called *updating*, and it is exactly the purpose of a VCS. You only need to type `hg update -r <revision>` to get to any point in the history, and to get back to where you currently are.

Type `hg help update` for more info.

Comment: Many thanks @Vince, this did exactly what I wanted. For info, before running this I ran hg log to see which revision to go back to and which to return to.